# EF Migration equivalent for sqlproj projects in VS

Tags: entity-framework, ef-database-first, entity-framework-migrations, sqlproj

We're evaluating a setup where we have a solution with two projects, one is an asp.net 5 project using EF7, the other is a full-blown sqlproj that actually manages the database. One thing I'm curious about is whether sqlproj has some kind of data migration support, similar to EF. Schema changes on their own seem relatively straightforward, but what's the best practice for schema changes which also require some data manipulation (e.g. merging two columns into one, or splitting a column in two, etc)?

Comment: Why not make the change in the sqlproj and reverse engineer the output from this into your codebase?

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what'll have to happen regarding code, but the real question is how to do data migrations within the sqlproj project. Idempotent scripts? Run once and delete? Etc. I was just hoping it would have something out of the box for this, but I might be missing something.

Comment: Ssdt (sqlproj) can handle a number of schema change scenarios